parLapply cannot find function in a custom package [R]
parLapply is unable to call a function in a custom package using clusterExport(cl, "func").
library(parallel)
func <- function(x) {
  output <- myPkg::myFunc(
    file = x,
    path = "/local/path"
  )
  output
}
vector = c("file1", "file2")

cluster <- makeCluster(10)
clusterEvalQ(cluster, library(myPkg))
clusterExport(cluster,  "func")

parLapply(cluster, vector, func)

parLapply reports
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
2 nodes produced errors; first error: argument "func" is missing, with no default
Note that "myFunc" relies on many other functions in the custom package, although I would think clusterEvalQ would pick them up without exporting to the cluster.

answer the question myself in case someone else encounters the same issue and is scratching their head
try reinstalling the custom package :)
